# Blank page after login on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, fbconnect

I'm using the iOS Facebook SDK, and have an app that uses the following code to post on a user's wall:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"Share on Facebook",      
@"user_message_prompt",
                        shareUrl, @"link",
                        imgUrl, @"picture",
                        nil];
[_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

as adapted from the example that comes with the SDK.

It used to work fine, very recently, it has started to break - you log in, then you're just presented with a blank page (with the facebook logo + blue stripe at the top).

The link the webView is pointing to is
http://m.facebook.com/#!/dialog/feed?_path=feed&app_id=177538815636301&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&sdk=2&display=touch&link=http%3A%2F%2Fxxxxx.xxxxx.com%2F%3Fcode%3D3dh574&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fxxxx.xxxxx.com%2Ffiles%2F3dh574.png&user_message_prompt=Share%20on%20Facebook&from_login=1&__user=100002342336489

If I open this link in my browser on my mac, it shows the correct page, but on the iPhone it's just a blank screen. No errors in the console or on the page itself.

I managed to get the webView contents, it looks like this:

```
window._sync_cstart = +new Date;
Facebook Mobilewindow.FB_GKS = {
    "moulder_feed": 1,
    "moulder_feed_hide_toggle": 0,
    "timeline_mobile": 0,
    "groups_faceweb": 0,
    "mobile_js_show_errorbox": 0,
    "mobile_js_show_debug": false
};
window.m_version = "M_siWj64";
document.cookie = "m_version=M_siWj64; path=\/"; /*<![CDATA[*/


function si_cj(m) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        new Image().src = "http:\/\/error.facebook.com\/common\/scribe_endpoint.php?c=si_clickjacking&t=3135" + "&m=" + m;
    }, 5000);
}
if (top != self && !false) {
    try {
        if (parent != top) {
            throw 1;
        }
        var si_cj_d = ["apps.facebook.com", "\/pages\/", "apps.beta.facebook.com"];
        var href = top.location.href.toLowerCase();
        for (var i = 0; i < si_cj_d.length; i++) {
            if (href.indexOf(si_cj_d[i]) >= 0) {
                throw 1;
            }
        }
        si_cj("3 http:\/\/m.facebook.com\/login.php?app_id=177538815636301&sdk=2&cancel=fbconnect\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fsuccess&next=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fm.facebook.com\u00252Fdialog\u00252Ffeed\u00253F_path\u00253Dfeed\u002526app_id\u00253D177538815636301\u002526redirect_uri\u00253Dfbconnect\u0025253A\u0025252F\u0025252Fsuccess\u002526sdk\u00253D2\u002526display\u00253Dtouch\u002526link\u00253Dhttp\u0025253A\u0025252F\u0025252Frefract.swarovski.com\u0025252F\u0025253Fcode\u0025253D3dh574\u002526picture\u00253Dhttp\u0025253A\u0025252F\u0025252Frefract.swarovski.com\u0025252Ffiles\u0025252F3dh574.png\u002526user_message_prompt\u00253DShare\u00252Bon\u00252BFacebook\u002526from_login\u00253D1&rcount=1&_rdr");
    } catch (e) {
        si_cj("1 \thttp:\/\/m.facebook.com\/login.php?app_id=177538815636301&sdk=2&cancel=fbconnect\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fsuccess&next=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fm.facebook.com\u00252Fdialog\u00252Ffeed\u00253F_path\u00253Dfeed\u002526app_id\u00253D177538815636301\u002526redirect_uri\u00253Dfbconnect\u0025253A\u0025252F\u0025252Fsuccess\u002526sdk\u00253D2\u002526display\u00253Dtouch\u002526link\u00253Dhttp\u0025253A\u0025252F\u0025252Frefract.swarovski.com\u0025252F\u0025253Fcode\u0025253D3dh574\u002526picture\u00253Dhttp\u0025253A\u0025252F\u0025252Frefract.swarovski.com\u0025252Ffiles\u0025252F3dh574.png\u002526user_message_prompt\u00253DShare\u00252Bon\u00252BFacebook\u002526from_login\u00253D1&rcount=1&_rdr");
        window.document.write("\u003cstyle>body * {display:none !important;}\u003c\/style>\u003ca href=\"#\" onclick=\"top.location.href=window.location.href\" style=\"display:block !important;padding:10px\">Go to Facebook.com\u003c\/a>"); /*B145Ecbc*/
    }
} /*]]>*/
Loading...Loading...MExceptionHandler.run(function () {
    JX.Stratcom.mergeData(0, {});
    MExceptionHandler.run(function () {
        JX.initBehaviors({
            "m-response": [],
            "m-page-error": [{
                "mobile_js_show_errorbox": 0,
                "mobile_js_show_debug": false
            }],
            "m-link": [],
            "ios-webapp": [],
            "m-verify-cache": [{
                "viewer": 100002342336489
            }],
            "usercheck": [{
                "user_id": 100002342336489
            }],
            "dtsg": [{
                "dtsg": {
                    "token": "AQB2zmo7",
                    "expire": 1318070716
                }
            }],
            "m-scroll-position-saver": [],
            "m-ajax-loader": [{
                "future": false
            }],
            "m-back-button": [],
            "m-blocking-touchable": []
        })
    }, "behavior");
}, "onload");
```

fbDidNotLogin callback is not called. No errors appear - I've put a lot of NSLog()'s in, pretty much in every method.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you gotten any work around for the same.